# How to fix "Socket creation in UltraProbe...Permission denied" error when using nmap?

Tags: command-line

I have a pre-compiled `nmap` binary for Android that was working properly and without error in LineageOS 14.1. The phone is a One Plus One.

Since upgrading to Lineage 15.1 (Android 8), the specific error I get is:

```
Socket creation in UltraProbe* sendConnectScanProbe(UltraScanInfo, HostScanStats, u16, u8, u8): Permission denied (13).
```

This is when `nmap` is run as the standard user, as root the phone becomes unresponsive and immediately crashes. I read somewhere over on SO that someone who was also attempting to open a socket was running into a permission issue as well, but successfully circumvented it by adding the user into these groups: `aid_bt`, `aid_bt_net`, `aid_inet`, `aid_net_raw`, `aid_admin`

It doesn't seem like this version of LineageOS has either `groupadd` or `usermod`, so that solution doesn't help me.

Did any changes occur between the two versions of Lineage that could cause this problem?
And how can I make `nmap` work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did any changes occur between the two versions of Lineage that could cause this problem

I don't have any experience with `nmap` and can't be sure why it worked with Android N, but Android has always been restrictive when it comes to socket access. I have been facing same issues at least from Marshmallow and onwards. `ping` is the common example.

> It doesn't seem like this version of LineageOS has either `groupadd` or `usermod`

Android's [users](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/libcutils/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#L53) and [permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) management is quite different than Linux. `Bionic libc` doesn't support many sycalls provided by standard `glibc`, particularly related to [NSS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75905973&postcount=2). Also, the related files `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, `/etc/shadow` and others don't exist on Android the way they exist on Linux. So, the standard Linux utilities `groupadd` and `useradd` etc. cannot be used on Android unless the source is modified and environment is modified accordingly.

> how can I make nmap work again?

If you want to use a `program` compiled  for standard Linux which needs capabilities `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`, `CAP_NET_ADMIN`, `CAP_NET_RAW` etc., the program needs to be run by a user who is member of Android groups `aid_inet`, `aid_admin` and `aid_net_raw`.  Even though the `root` user has apparently `CAP_NET_*` capabilities, [socket syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) fails if it is not added to these groups explicitly. Most of the times only `aid_inet` suffices.

For instance, let's view capabilities of `wpa_supplicant` (process responsible for making wi-fi connections) on Android:

```
~$ su -c "getpcaps $(pidof wpa_supplicant)"
Capabilities for `21224': = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep
```

So, `nmap` won't work unless executed with its required capabilities. A capability is a subset of root permissions.

Terminal apps are usually already member of `aid_net` group (`android.permission.INTERNET`). However if it's not the case or you want to create a Linux type user on Android, follow on.

**ADD LINUX USER ON ANDROID**

*NOTE:* Device must be rooted.

On Linux, [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) are assigned to a user (a user is a process id in fact, usually a shell) by some login mechanism, `PAM` modules being the most common. But there is no user login on Android, so we need to replicate that somehow. Lets create a Linux user, say "irfan" on Android.

Better is to use the UID of terminal app assigned at the time of app installation or you can use any unused UID like 6000.

Modify or create the files as below:

```
# /etc/passwd
irfan:x:10129:10129::/sdcard:/system/bin/sh
root:x:0:0::/data/local/tmp:/system/bin/sh
```

```
# /etc/group
aid_inet:x:3003:irfan,root
```

To login as user "irfan" with `aid_inet` as secondary group, use a [*Linux aware* busybox](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/tool-busybox-flashable-archs-t3348543) `su binary` which regards `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`:

```
~$ id
uid=10129(u0_a129) gid=10129(u0_a129) groups=10129(u0_a129),9997(everybody)

~$ su -c 'busybox su - irfan'

~$ busybox id
uid=10129(irfan) gid=10129(irfan) groups=10129(irfan),3003(aid_inet)
```

Please note the usage of `su` twice. First `su` is the one you get when you root your device. It's because `su` must be executed with `CAP_SETUID` capability. But normal Android apps run without any capability:

```
~$ capsh --print | grep Bounding
Bounding set =
```

The first `su` grants us that capability (and all other capabilities) as well as avoids the need to `setuid` on `busybox  su` binary.

In the same way you can add yourself to as many groups as you want, `everybody`, `sdcard_rw` and so on.

**SOURCE:**

- [How Linux capabilities work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user/17685265#17685265)
- [Root User and Linux Capabilities: Linux vs. Android](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77437874&postcount=6)