# How to create system users on Androidx86?

Tags: android-x86, busybox

I am trying to create system users on an [Android x86](https://www.android-x86.org/) virtual machine, but the binaries `adduser` and `addgroup` don't exist (neither `useradd` or `usermod`). I installed [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/) to get access to these utilities but when trying to run `addgroup` to create a new system group I get error `addgroup: /etc/group: No such file or directory`. When trying to run `adduser` with an existing system group I get error `adduser: unknown group net_bt_admin`.

The only way to create users I found so far is through `pm create-user`, but these are android level users, how can I create users quivalent to `shell` or `system` default users?

Comment: android "misuses" [uid](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208523)'s for it's app restrictions, there exist no "users" and one must not mess up file permissions. `pm create-user` is for creating profiles

Comment: Also related: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209921/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201285/218526).