# How to add new user to group, modify user/group, or log in as root on Android?

Tags: terminal, root-access

I have my crappy Samsung J5 (6) phone and after rooting it, I want to do something. I'm testing what happens if I add the current user to the root group. My username is `j5xnlte`, but when I try `usermod`, it says

```
sush: usermod: not found
```

What commands I ran and the output:

```
j5xnlte:/ $ whoami
u0_a102
j5xnlte:/ $ su
j5xnlte:/ # whoami
root
j5xnlte:/ # usermod
sush: usermod: not found
127|
j5xnlte:/ # exit
127|
j5xnlte:/ $ usermod
/system/bin/sh: usermod: not found
```

Maybe I don't have the ability to mess with users or groups? How I can add a user to a group on Android? I also want to know how to log in on Android as root or create a new user.

Comment: In the GUI you can never login as root. Each app runs on it's own user, thus you have no Linux user account but a lot of them. User account management is done by Android system. The only way to execute something as root is on command-line (via `su`) e.g. in adb shell or Termux shell. Apps that can make of root do exactly that in background.

Comment: See these answers to understand Android users and login process: [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201285/218526), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526), [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209053/218526), [4](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221825/218526).

Comment: Is there no way to login as root, I guess it is possible to give root permission to every normal user by editing the Kernel